# Nightmare JS updating MongoDB + Mongoose with retrieved data not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nightmare

I am looking to scrape data from specific URLs and updating an existing data in MongoDB. I am also using CRON (not sure if that has any affect on the code). Below is the code:

```
module.exports = new CronJob('0 */59 * * * *', function() {
nightmare
    .goto('http://www.xyzxyzxyz.com/')
    .wait(2000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        var itemS = [];
        var itemList = document.querySelectorAll('.item-list');
            for(var i = 0; i < item-list.length; i++) {
                var item = {};
                item['name'] = itemList[i].querySelector('.item-title').innerHTML;
                item['image'] = itemList[i].querySelector('.item-image').src;
                itemS.push(item);
            }
        return itemS;
    })
    //.end() -- removed because CRON does not restart
    .then(function(result) {
        var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("589b8d8fe860591071d4e2c6");
        mongooseModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set: {key: result}}, function(err, res) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('success!');
            }
        });
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Search failed:', error);
    });
```

}, null, true);

the results are console.log(ged) (console.log(result)) but the console.log("success!") callback does not execute.

Also, unrelated, when I pull images from some sites, I'm getting Data URLs instead of the img url. I tried putting the data URL directly into a  tag, but the image shows up blank -- I also tried decoding the image, using online resources, but the image still does not render. any possible solutions for this?

Thanks so much, in advance!

Comment: If success is not outputted, what does this line output? `if(err) {console.log(err);}`

Comment: it doesn't output anything either, which is why it's so frustrating...